# Dictionary versus NumPy array performance Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, matrix

I am working with multiple NumPy 2-dimension arrays (matrices), and I want to get some rows, or columns, from them (same rows or columns indexes for each of the 3 matrices, each time). I was wondering if I should use dictionary or not.

If I do it with a dictionary, then each row of each matrix would be indexed by a word, and would a list of values that interest me. E.g, `myDict['word']` would contain `[1 5 2 49 0 2]`.

If I do it with an array `myArray`, for each `i` I would have an array contained within `myArray[i]`. E.g, `myArray[5]` would contain `array([[1 2 4 9 1 23]])`.

On these I need to implement basic `get` operations (get rows or get columns), some matrix multiplications but never sorting or insertions.
I know I can do it both ways, my question is mainly of performance. Which do you think would be the faster and simplier?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: A third option would be python dictionaries of numpy 1D arrays, not lists. You'd recover some readability like `myDict['myRowOfApples']` and still have the fast multiplication. You'd have to duplicate the data though, having rows and columns stored in different keys of a same dict or in two different dicts, one for rows and one for columns. If performance is not critical go for readability.

Answer (score 3):

For matrix operation, I strongly recommend numpy, to justify my choice, I want first to quote wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy

*"... any algorithm that can be expressed primarily as operations on arrays and matrices can run almost as quickly as the equivalent C code."*

Besides that I notice that you want to have matrix multiplication functionality. Numpy provides you that, and of course in an efficient way.